# How to add the layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add the layout dynamically. Actually in my app i am making comment section. The view for comment i have made in the LinearLayout and inside that i have added the ImageView(UserPics), Edittext and Post button.

XML for comments is like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/commment_section"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nmd_user_img"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cmt_user_image"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:background="@color/layout_bg"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cmt_user_edt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmt_user_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:hint="Enter your comments"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, since multiple user can add the comments . I want as soon as a user enters the comment a new layout like this should get added dynamically below the previous comment.

Comment: Create `RelativeLayout` layout dynamically which is inside `commment_section` layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a xml view of comment row and inflate it runtime and add it to the parent View.

Let say comment.xml is the view of comment row to be added dynamically so to inflate it follow below:

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View commentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);
        commentView.setId(commentID);
        yourLinearLayout.addView(commentView);
```

You can set anything in the comment row using the view object and calling findViewById. In this way no layout preparation code is in java file that make it really simple like we use to do in getView of adapter :)

If you got stuck anywhere in the steps please let me know.

Comment: ok .. If i want to add the id dynamically to the Relativelayout can it be done.. For Ex: Like comment_id1, comment_id2....

Comment: yes you can set the id on the new view inflated by calling setId() on the view, but why you want a new id for each comment. I have edited my answer with the ID part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have id on `LinearLayout`

then in `java` file

```
Relativelayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
yourLinearLayout.addView(rl);
```

For setting ID to your Layout

```
someLayout.setId (12); //ID should be of integer type.
```

Comment: can i add the id for the relativeLayout dynamically... for each complaint i want to maintain an id...